# Simple division with high precision in Mathematica

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I want to do a simple division i.e. `0.70524/0.51824` . What I want is to find the result of the roundation of this division for precision from 1 to 19 decimal digits. So what I do is:

`For[i = 1, i < 19, i++,
       Print[N[Round[0.70524/0.51824, 10^-i], i+1]]
 ]`

So I get the following 19 values. 

`1.4
1.36 
1.361
1.3608 
1.36084
1.360837
1.3608367
1.36083668
1.360836678
1.3608366780
1.36083667799 
1.360836677987 
1.3608366779870 
1.36083667798703
1.360836677987033 
1.3608366779870330
1.36083667798703280 
1.360836677987032832
1.3608366779870328832`

But as you can see after the 17th loop the results are wrong. If you round `1.360836677987032832` to 17 digits you should get `1.36083667798703283` but you get `1.36083667798703280`. What do I do wrong? Is there a solution to that? Isn't it the same as in the case of N[1/3, 20] where I get correct results?

Comment: You are doing arithmetic on machine doubles, and that works at about 16 digits. You cannot get more digits after the fact.

Comment: But the answer of Rohit Namjoshi is working. You say that these values are not correct?

Comment: I made no such claim (I did not comment on that response). Take another look at that code. In contrast to yours, it is doing division on exact values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For[i = 1, i < 19, i++, Print[N[Round[70524/51824, 10^-i], i + 1]]]
```

Comment: Do you know why my code isn't working? I mean it is the same division. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @AlexSpanos See @Daniel's comment above. For more details on why `0.70524/0.51824` is not the same as `70524/51824`see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html)